# Issues with mysqli select all

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using MySQLi connection and I have the following code, i am trying to select all columns for a row defined by inventory id from a database table but i can't get this to work. Am i doing it the totally wrong way? I want to be able to use things like `$row['general_cleanliness']` in my code following the select query.

```
$getScheduleCondition = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE inventory_id = ? LIMIT 1",)){
$getScheduleCondition->bind_param("i", $inventory);
$row = $getScheduleCondition->fetch_array();
$getScheduleCondition->close();
```

`$inventory` is defined as a number, i know this works. Any help is appreciated, sorry if this seems like a basic question, just a little confusing!

EDIT:
For everyone telling me i'm using PDO, i'm not:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'cl52-system', 'PASS', 'cl52-system');
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Comment: " select all rows from a database" - but why in you code you select by id and set limit 1?

Comment: You never execute the query (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: @sergio sorry i meant columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting two things. First you need to execute the query. You can do this with `your_stmt_object->execute()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)). Your stmt-object doesn't have a method `fetch_array()` though, so you first need to pull a `mysqli_result` out of it with `->get_result()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)) and then you can use `fetch_array()` as you want.

```
$getScheduleCondition = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE inventory_id = ? LIMIT 1");
$getScheduleCondition->bind_param("i", $inventory);
$getScheduleCondition->execute(); //You need to execute the query
$row = $getScheduleCondition->get_result()->fetch_array(); //From stmt to mysql_result to array
$getScheduleCondition->close();
```

If you don't need to use the array, it might be easier to use `->fetch()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)) and `->bind_result()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)) instead.

```
$getScheduleCondition = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE inventory_id = ? LIMIT 1");
$getScheduleCondition->bind_param("i", $inventory);
$getScheduleCondition->bind_result( $column1, $column2, $column3, $etc );
$getScheduleCondition->execute(); //You need to execute the query
$getScheduleCondition->fetch(); //Now the first row is in the variables defined above
echo $column1; //<-- see?
$getScheduleCondition->close();
```

Comment: my old query used the bind_result. Probably is there is so many columns, i wanted to simplify it with select *. I'll try your first suggestion

Comment: I've tried the first option, now it just kills my script. Any ideas?

Comment: Prosecute it for murder. Alternativelly find out what error it gives. If it gives no visible error (and you have php errors on), `var_dump` all variables involved and see if one or more give strange results. If the first line gives an error (prepared statement), manually execute the query on the database to see if there is any mysql error. Alternativelly, if you have done a prepared query before that moment, that query might not have been properly closed.

Comment: I cant get any errors to show but it is the line of $row = $getScheduleCondition->get_result()->fetch_array(); //From stmt to mysql_result to array that is causing my page to go blank

Answer (score -2):

The parameter your passing is identified as "i" (named parameter), but in your query only have ?, change your bind_param to ":i" and change the ? to :i in your query.

```
    $getScheduleCondition = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE inventory_id = :i LIMIT 1",)){
    $getScheduleCondition->bind_param(":i", $inventory, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $getScheduleCondition->execute(); // based on Sumurai8 comment, this is missing
    $row = $getScheduleCondition->fetch_array();
    $getScheduleCondition->close();
```

also, the PDO:PARAM_INT explicitly sets the parameter to an integer.

Comment: The connection works fine because what i used to use is fine, i'm trying to simplify my code, i don't believe this is the answer but i will try it

Comment: It is set as an integer, im using mysqli

Comment: Updated question, i'm using mysqli

Comment: This question is not about PDO @Gerbenny